# What is the difference between cvpartition and crossvalind

Tags: matlab, classification

```
load fisheriris;
y = species; %label
X = meas;

%Create a random partition for a stratified 10-fold cross-validation.

c = cvpartition(y,'KFold',10);
%  split training/testing sets
[trainIdx testIdx] = crossvalind('HoldOut', y, 0.6);
```

`crossvalind` is used to perform cross-validation by randomly splitting the entire feature set `X` into training and testing data by returning the indices. Using the indices, we can create train and test data as `X(trainIdx,:)` and `X(testIdx,:)` respectively. `cvpartition` also splits the data using methods such as stratified and non-stratified but it does not return the indices. I have not seen examples where `crossvalind` is a stratified or non-stratified technique.

Question: Can `crossvalind` and `cvpartition` be used together?

I want to do stratified cross-validation. But I don't understand how to divide the data sets into train and test and get the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-validation and train/test partitioning are two different ways of *estimating the performance of a model*, not different ways of building the model itself. Usually you should build a model using all the data that you have, but also use one of these techniques (which build and score one or more additional models using subsets of that data) to estimate how good the main model is likely to be.

Cross-validation averages the outcome of multiple train/test splits so is usually expected to give a more realistic i.e. more pessimistic estimate of model performance.

Of the two functions you mention,`crossvalind` appears to be specific to the Bioinformatics Toolbox and is rather old. The [help](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition-class.html) for `cvpartition` gives an example of how to do a stratified cross-validation:

> **Examples**
>
> Use a 10-fold stratified cross validation to compute the
>   misclassification error for classify on iris data.
>
> ```
> load('fisheriris');
> CVO = cvpartition(species,'k',10);
> err = zeros(CVO.NumTestSets,1);
> for i = 1:CVO.NumTestSets
>     trIdx = CVO.training(i);
>     teIdx = CVO.test(i);
>     ytest = classify(meas(teIdx,:),meas(trIdx,:),...
>        species(trIdx,:));
>     err(i) = sum(~strcmp(ytest,species(teIdx)));
> end
> cvErr = sum(err)/sum(CVO.TestSize);
> ```

Comment: Cross-validation doesn't improve your model, it improves your estimate of how good your model is (usually by making it look worse, because if you don't cross-validate you tend to get over-optimistic estimates).

Comment: That's probably specific to the type of model you are using so I would read up the help for that model type and ask a new question if it's unclear.

Comment: on your answer at the end line it shows an error rate, I'm little confused what's that mean, I used your codes with 500 observation and received 0.3358, what's this mean? It means my model will works bad?

Comment: @motevalizadeh Look at the code, and the help for `cvpartition` if you need to. `cvErr` is the sum of `err` divided by the total size of all the test sets. `err` is a vector with 1 element for each test set, and each element (`err(i)`) is the number of instances where the classification according to the model didn't match the true class. So `cvErr` is the fraction of the whole dataset where the model got the classification wrong, in the cross-validation. Another way of putting that would be that you got a cross-validated accuracy of 66.42%. Is that good or bad? Depends on your problem.